# Can I erase or reformat a Linux RAID drive using Terminal on Mac

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mac, raid, format

Or by any other means basically. This is what diskutil list gives me.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't have a mac, but if you want to totally wipe the drive so you can repartition it and reformat it, I am pretty sure you can do a "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk4 bs=1024 count=1" which will wipe the entire setup of the drive and hopefully allow you to repartition and format as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk4 bs=1024 count=1` suggested by [davidgo](https://superuser.com/users/137786/davidgo) in the comments will only wipe the first 1024 bytes from the disk.

For a MBR partitioning, that would have been enough to completely wipe the partition table. But the text `GUID_partition_scheme` indicates this disk uses GPT partitioning.

A GPT partition table can be larger than 1024 bytes. And even if the primary GPT partition table has been totally wiped, there's a backup copy of it at the very end of the disk.

Nevertheless, `diskutil eraseDisk` should work just fine; choose the options according to what you plan to do with the disk later.